# SVG changed syntax after e-mailing it

Tags: html, css, svg, syntax

could someone explain to me how to make this code work again? I notice that my interpreter, visual studio code, doesn't recognise the entire style code that is placed within

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- (c) ammap.com | SVG weather icons -->
    <svg
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="64"
        height="64"
        viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <defs>
            <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
                <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
                <feComponentTransfer>
                    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feMerge> 
                    <feMergeNode/>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
     <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
    path {
      fill: #EDF1FF;
      stroke: #C9C9C9;
      stroke-width: 0.45px;
    }
     ]]>
        </style>
        </defs>
        <g filter="url(#blur)" id="rainy-5">
            <g transform="translate(20,10)">
                <g>
                     <path d="M47.7,35.4c0-4.6-3.7-8.2-8.2-8.2c-1,0-1.9,0.2-2.8,0.5c-0.3-3.4-3.1-6.2-6.6-6.2c-3.7,0-6.7,3-6.7,6.7c0,0.8,0.2,1.6,0.4,2.3    c-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1-0.1c-3.7,0-6.7,3-6.7,6.7c0,3.6,2.9,6.6,6.5,6.7l17.2,0C44.2,43.3,47.7,39.8,47.7,35.4z" fill="#EDF1FF" 
    transform="translate(-20,-11)"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Chrome console shows the following error when executing your code snippet: _“Error: `<path>` attribute d: Expected number, "…-0.3-3.4-3.1-6.2- 6.6-6.2c-3.7,0…".”_ - you have whitespace in the content of the `d` attribute here in multiple places where where shouldn’t be any, so remove that. `2- 6`, `2.3    c-0`, `7,3- 6.7`

Answer (score 0):

I made a syntax error that 04FS kindly pointed out to me. thank you!!